# RxJava - Subscribe doesn't catch exception which cause crash

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I am trying to subscribe to a `SingleSource`, I have implemented both `onSuccess` And `onError` of `subscribe` method, here is my code:

```
disposable.add(repository
                .getUser1()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    toast(it)
                }, {
                    toast(it.message ?: "Error")
                }))
```

The Problem is When an exception occur in repository it does't being caught in `onError`

Here is my repository implementation:

```
class Repository(private val sp: SharedPreferences) {

    // It crashes
    fun getUser1(): Single<String> = generateUser(name, "Hello")

    // it doesn't crash
    fun getUser2(): Single<String> = Single.fromCallable { name }.flatMap { generateUser(it, "Hello") }

    private var name: String
        get() = sp.getString("user", null) ?: throw NoNameException()
        set(value) = sp.edit().putString("user", value).apply()

    private fun generateUser(name: String, message: String): Single<String> = Single.just("$message $name")

}
```

And here is the crash Log:

> 09-24 10:13:40.930 6934-6934/com.mosius.samplerxtest E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.mosius.samplerxtest, PID: 6934
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826) 
>        Caused by: com.mosius.samplerxtest.NoNameException: No Name Supplied
>           at com.mosius.samplerxtest.Repository.getName(Repository.kt:17)
>           at com.mosius.samplerxtest.Repository.getUser1(Repository.kt:10)
>           at com.mosius.samplerxtest.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:24)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>           at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25881)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)

What's the different between these two implementation?

Comment: It should be no functional difference between `Single.subscribe` with separate `Consumer`'s or with a single `BiConsumer`. The problem could be caused by many reasons, it's hard to say anything until the code is shown. If you really looking for the answer, I would suggest, to try to reproduce the same in small scale. Make a small project and share link here. Than it would be much easier to say "why" and "how to fix".

Comment: @AlexanderSkvortsov I will create one and share the link here, thanks

Comment: @AlexanderSkvortsov As you said, the problem was not related to callBack implementation, actually it throw a `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` Exception which I have too find out why it happens, I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getUser1()` method, `SingleSource` has not been created yet, so it is out of Rx control to handle the exception.

In the Second one the name is being fetched in Rx scope therefore it could handle the exception

Comment: I am glad that you found the answer by yourself. 